# Subversion: unix permissions on disk for secure apache access

Tags: svn, security, apache, unix

I moved a Subversion repository from a Windows box to a UNIX machine. In both environments I've handled authentication through Apache.

On the UNIX box after the move, I could checkout source but received the following error when committing anything:

```
svn: Can't open file '/home/brianly/svn/test/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied
```

It seemed to be a UNIX permission issue and the following command resolves the issue:

```
chmod -R 777 /home/brianly/svn/test
```

Now, I've opened this up to be writable by all users (right?). Is there a security issue with doing this? Should I have changed the owner to be the apache user (daemon) instead? What's the best practice for setting the file system permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do is change the directory owner to the apache process user, e.g.

```
chown -R apache /home/brianly/svn/test
```

You need to run `chown` as root (directly or through `sudo`).

You can see who the user is with (if it's linux):

```
ps -fadeww|grep httpd
```

And don't forget to change it back to 755 or 700 or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

If the only access is through HTTP, then you can limit access to the user the web server runs under.  Right now with 777, this is not only a security risk with respect to local users but also a loss of permissions as you have just made executables files that should not be... See orip's answer for the rest.